# how to implement a CreateMany mutation resolver in prisma-graphql

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql

i want to write a mutation resolver that creates multiple items.It takes a list of items as arguments.I tried to loop through the set of items using map function and apply create single item mutation on each item. But it is not working.
My code :

```
datamodel:
type Item {
id: ID!@id
title: String!
}

type Mutation {
createItem(title:String):Item // creates a single item
createMultiple(batch:[ItemCreateInput]):AggregateItem  // not working
}
```

the input to batch was [ {title:"abc"}, {title:"cbe"} ]

prisma.graphql:

```
type AggregateItem {
   count: Int!
 } 
input ItemCreateInput {
 id: ID
 title: String!
 }
createItem(data: ItemCreateInput!): Item!
```

i tried doing:

```
async createMultiple(parent,args,info,ctx){
multipleItems = args.batch;
multipleItems.map(item =>  
const Item =  ctx.db.mutation.createItem({  // got error TypeError: Cannot read property 'mutation' of undefined
   data:{...item}
},info)}
```

Comment: You really need to show us an [mre]. I doubt you've given enough information for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

As @DavidW said, you did not provide enough information, such as `GraphQL server` configuration.

According to my guess, your `GraphQL server` configuration is incorrect, or you are not using it correctly.

To use `ctx.db.mutation`, you need your configuration as follows

```js
// Use graphql-yoga in the demo,
// if you use other GraphQLServer,
// you need to configure according to the official documentation.
import { prisma } from '../generated/prisma-client'
const { GraphQLServer } = require('graphql-yoga')

const server = new GraphQLServer({
  typeDefs: './schema.graphql',
  resolvers,
  context: {
    // The context injected here corresponds to the fourth parameter in the resolvers ctx
    db: prisma,
  },
})
```

Comment: My server configuration is the exact same code as the one you've written. Also ctx.db.mutation is working for other mutations. It isn't working only for this.

Comment: Can you create a demo on CodeSandbox or GitHub so that I can more accurately determine your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is actually very close. I achieved this functionality by using concatenation after each database write, rather than simply assigning each mutation to a variable.

Try something like this (this is assuming args.batch is a list of strings)

```
async createMultiple(parent,args,info,ctx){
var items = []
multipleItems = args.batch;
multipleItems.map(item =>  
items =  items.concat(ctx.db.mutation.createItem({
   data:{
      item: item
   }
}))
)
return items
```